# Dynamic rolling function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, signal-processing

I am trying to implement a dynamic moving average and other dynamic moving functions like `std` and `max` in Pandas. The difference between the 'normal' and the dynamic moving average is the behaviour at the edges. This mainly improves two things:

- the returned data is **not** shifted as with the 'normal' moving average
- the returned data covers the **whole** range of the input data. Using the 'normal' moving average the returned data range is cropped depending on the window size of the moving average.

So to get a dynamic moving average there are multiple methods like *reflection, repetition of first/last value, ...*  For me the *reflection method* is enough. This and the other behaviours are implemented in the filters from `scripy.ndimage.filters`, e.g. the `uniform_filter1d`. I've looked through Pandas documentation but on `rolling` I could not find any arguments which changes the behaviour at the edges...
Adding this myself seems doable but I am asking the question to see if there is already an implementation in Pandas which I've missed.

So my question can be reduced to that: Is there a way to use Pandas `rolling` dynamically like I described?

**'Normal' moving average**:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage import filters


def moving_avg(series: pd.Series, window: int) -> pd.Series:
    return series.rolling(window=window).mean()


t = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 0.03 * t)

filtered_y = filters.uniform_filter1d(y, 200)

pd_y = pd.Series(y, name="Pandas Moving Average")
pd_y = moving_avg(pd_y, 200) # Using a large window on purpose to show the shift!

plt.plot(y, label="Raw Data")
plt.plot(filtered_y, label="uniform_filter1d")
pd_y.plot()
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

**Result**

[image: Difference in rolling behaviour]

So is there something to solve this problem?

Comment: Why can't you use the `scipy` filters?

Comment: I will use different Pandas `rolling` methods like `std` and `max`, but I only found `uniform_filter1d` to be similar to the result I expect from `mean`.

Comment: @Drachen first the "shift" can be addressed using the parameter `center=True` in the `rolling` method

Comment: Yes I read about this parameter, but that doesn't change the edge behaviour. Is there a way to implement the `rolling` function dynamically?

Comment: @Drachen you just look for an easy way to implement the mode reflect of `uniform_filter1d` in pandas rolling?

Comment: How you came up with 200 number?

Comment: @Ben.T yes kinda. I try to make the rolling function behave dynamic like I explained, so use the new dynamic `rolling().mean` should produces similar results to the `uniform_filter1d`:)

Comment: @Harry_pb this is just an arbitrary value, I chose it to be high to show the shift induced by the `rolling` function in Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is what you want implemented. One easy way is to use `concat` to add the edges values to create the reflect effect. In a function, it could be something like

```
def rolling_reflect_center(s, window):
    nb_ref = window // 2
    rolling_ = pd.concat(
        [pd.Series(s.iloc[:nb_ref].values)[::-1],#reflect on the left
         s, 
         pd.Series(s.iloc[-nb_ref+1:].values[::-1]) #reflect on the right
        ]).rolling(window ,center=True)
    return rolling_
```

then you do

```
filtered_y = filters.uniform_filter1d(y, 200)

pd_y = pd.Series(y, name="Pandas Moving Average")
pd_y = rolling_reflect_center( pd_y, window=200).mean()

print(np.allclose(pd_y.dropna().to_numpy(),filtered_y))
#True
```

the plot works well too because it drops the `nan` automatically

Comment: Thank you Ben.T for your effort. I think there is no implementation in Pandas which creates the same effect (edge behaviour, 'shift') and your solutions works fine, so accepting your answer!:)